# Chinese New Year Date on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar

How one could get Chinese New Year Date on Android?

Since API level 24 Android has Chinese Calendar class.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/ChineseCalendar

However, doing it like this returns wrong date (Feb 12 for 2023).

```
    val chinese = ChineseCalendar.getInstance()
    chinese.set(ChineseCalendar.MONTH, 0)
    chinese.set(ChineseCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
```

Comment: this is what document has mention which i can see clearly difference

```ChineseCalendar usually should be instantiated using Calendar.getInstance(ULocale) passing in a ULocale with the tag "@calendar=chinese".```

source :- 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/ChineseCalendar

Comment: I was unable to get right day using this method

Comment: So you should add that code also so if anything is wrong in day fetching then it can be solved .. over here i am assuming date was correct using method mentioned in documentation ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want - a gregorian date of Chinese new year, which for 2023 is Jan 22

Comment: Or you use my lib Time4A which can also be used below API24. See http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/ChineseCalendar.html Please keep in mind that the astronomical calculations of ICU4J (which was adopted by Android) are not always accurate.

Comment: @MenoHochschild, thanks! I will have this as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get Gregorian date for Chinese new year in the following way. Getting Chinese calendar is done using simple instantiation `ChineseCalendar()`. No need to call `getInstance()`.

```
    val chinese = ChineseCalendar()
    chinese.set(ChineseCalendar.MONTH, 0)
    chinese.set(ChineseCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    println("chinese " + chinese.time.toString())
```

In the logs I got

`chinese Sun Jan 22 13:24:41 GMT+02:00 2023`

You can also add year to get next new year date, like this

```
    chinese.add(ChineseCalendar.YEAR, 1)
```

and get

`chinese Sat Feb 10 13:27:41 GMT+02:00 2024`